# Discord.js: Why does "awaitMessages" not work in event: "ready"?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Why does "awaitMessages" not work in "ready" ?

An error occurs after sending a message to a specific channel.

```
client.on('ready', () => {

    async function gift_start(client) {
        //...

        get_channel = client.guilds.cache.get(x.id).channels.cache.get(x.channel)
        let flag = await get_channel.send({ embed }).awaitMessages(message => !message.bot && captha === message.content.toLowerCase(), { max: 1, time: 10 * 1000, errors: ["time"] }).catch(() => 0);

        if (flag) {
            get_channel.send('Good!')
        } else {
            get_channel.send('No answer!')
        }

        //...
    }

    setInterval(gift_start, 20000, client);
})
```

Comment: what error ? show error message

Comment: Error: (node:16696) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: get_channel.send(...).awaitMessages is not a function

Comment: what you receive after await get channel.send({ embed }) split this to two functions ??  mean run awaitMessages in separate step. if send return promise then you can interact with it only by .then

Comment: message.channel.send('this message will be deleted').then(sentMessage => sentMessage.delete({ timeout: 10000 }))

Answer (score 0):

send() doesn't have awaitMessage function, channel does.

```js
    message.channel.send("").then(msg => {
     const flag = msg.channel.awaitMessages(message => !message.bot && captha === message.content.toLowerCase(), { max: 1, time: 10 * 1000, errors: ["time"] }).then(collected => collected.first()).catch(() => 0)
     //...your code here
    })
```